# Python modules: how to keep private symbol table private?

Tags: python, module

I have a module in which I import other modules (typically `sys` or `os`), and when I import the module with

```
import mymodule
```

if I do something like this

```
dir(mymodule)
```

I get not only the submodules of the module, but also `os` *et al.*

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'os', 'sys', 'submodule']
```

Is there a way to avoid to have the modules imported inside my module to show up in the symbol table of the module? Is it possible to keep it private?

Comment: What is the purpose of hiding `os` or `sys` module in listing ?

Comment: `dir()` is a **debug tool**. Are you sure you want to decapitate that tool?

Comment: Also, if you code *in the module* uses `os` and `sys`, then you cannot remove them from your namespace. They are in use, and removing them would break your code. Besides, the names are just *references*.

Comment: Last but not least, if you want to keep stuff private, you may not want to use Python. Python is *highly introspectable*. There isn't really such a thing as 'private'.

Comment: Use `__all__` if you want to communicate what the public API is for your module. Otherwise, you should not worry about those names in the module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I didn't want to behead `dir()`, I just used the command to get the list of stuff imported by the module. Perhaps I misanderstood the way Python is working with modules, and I was afraid it was a killover to import some modules twice with two different namespaces. I also thought that it could be confusing for another user of the module to see other modules appearing as submodules of the imported one.

Comment: @Lafada `os` or `sys` were given just as examples. It seemed clearer to me to use real examples than "any random and generic module".

Comment: @MBR: the behaviour is entirely normal. You are looking at the global namespace for everything in that module; if functions or generator expressions in that module use `os` or `sys`, then that is where they'll find those names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really any such thing as 'private' in Python; you use a leading underscore on names if you want to *communicate* that a name is private. Experienced Python developers will understand that those names should not really be used outside of the module.

`dir()` (really a debug tool) is showing you the global namespace of your module and you shouldn't worry about seeing imported modules in that list; this is *entirely normal*. Any code in that module (in functions or generator expressions) that uses `sys` or `os` or `submodule` as a global name, resolve the reference from that namespace. As such you *want* those names to be there for your code to continue working.

You can create a sequence with the name `__all__` in your global namespace to list all names you want others to use from your module. `dir()` won't use it, but syntax like `from mymodule import *` and `help(mymodule)` do honour that sequence.

You could also give those modules you imported 'private' names:

```
import os as _os
import sys as _sys
```

and update all references in your code to use those updated names. If you haven't set `__all__` then `from mymodule import *` and `help(mymodule)` will at least ignore names that start with an underscore.

And you can always use `del os` or `del sys` if you only used those modules at the top level, and no functions in your code require these names to exist as globals.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can delete the module from the namespace using `del`:

```
import os

# ... all other code here

del os
```

After that it won't be visible anymore when importing.

However, this won't work when the modules are actually used...

Comment: If I do that then it breaks my module; it would be better if it does not break anything!